# UI5 Module Namespace

Tags: sapui5

i have an app A that has a 'module' in it (actually, a folder with a bunch of files in it that together provide a specific functionaliy for app A). the 'module' is using the namespace of app A.

i am developing app B. i need to add the 'module' from app A - using copy and paste for now...
i need to manaully go in and change the namespace for the 'module' in app B so that file pahs are correct. ie so that they do not refer to app A.

is there a way to give the 'module' its own namespace so that it could be dded to a third app if required with a minimum of manual updates.

hope this makes sense.
thanks in advance.
pas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to work with directory then you can use gulp/grunt. These javascript task runner can help you copy a directory from one location to another. After that, you can use then look for string replace.

Look into gulp-copy and gulp-string-replace